# Caddy server with proxy to hugo server failing to load CSS

Tags: linode, hugo, caddy, caddyfile

I'm running a caddy server on a linode instance with debian installed.  I'm using the caddy server to proxy to a hugo server.  The hugo server works locally, but does not through the caddy server.  It will load the content, but `style.min.css` and the favicons won't load with an error like the following:

> GET https://localhost:8081/css/style.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Any help getting this working would be great!

**Caddyfile:**

```
mycustomdomain.com {
  root /home/sean/mycustomdomain.com
  gzip
  proxy / localhost:8081
  tls {
    dns linode
  }
}
```

**hugo command:**

```
hugo server --disableLiveReload --port 8081
```

Comment: Why are you proxying to a hugo server, especially without live reload enabled? Why not just let Caddy serve the static files?

Comment: Is the hugo server actually serving over https?

Comment: @matt Because hugo is not the only thing I'll be serving up on my linode  box.  The liveReloading piece is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @TobyAllen I was under the impression that hugo automatically served over https, but I'm not sure how to confirm that other than it only says it's serving `Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 127.0.0.1)` which doesn't appear to be https.

Comment: Hugo does not serve HTTPS by default. Only Caddy does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, so answering for posterity:

To resolve this, utilize the `http.hugo` plugin.  The new `Caddyfile` looks like so:

```
mycustomdomain.com {
  root /hugo/site/dir/public
  hugo /hugo/site/dir
  gzip
  tls {
    dns linode
  }
}
```

Comment: This plugin is now gone: https://caddy.community/t/where-is-http-hugo-plugin/5118